# Excel VBA pass parameter to OLEDBConnection

Tags: vba, excel

In an Excel workbook I have several connections to a SQL Server DB.  I thought I could run a small script like the one below, but it's not doing what I want.  I want to refresh the OLEDBConnection, and pass in a StartDate and EndDate, but it's not actually communicating with the connection.

```
Sub RefreshWithDates()

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date

StartDate = Sheets("Pivot_Summary").Range("B1").Value
EndDate = Sheets("Pivot_Summary").Range("B2").Value

    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("FMDDATA_HIST_SPLIT").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RECONCILIATION.dbo.TBL_FMDDATA_HIST_SPLIT Where AsOfDate between '" & StartDate & "' & " And " & '" & EndDate & "'"
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("FMDDATA_HIST_SPLIT").Refresh
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps it is communicating but failing because the date format that your sql server expects is not the same that VBA holds for a date. Consider using the `Test()` function to change the format like `Text(StartDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` in your sql.

Comment: Oh, I see how it works now.  You have to set Command Type = Default and then the Command Text is updated accordingly.  That's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.CommandText` string has an error around the `AND` (notice how it is blue in color... it is resolving as the VBA keyword `And`).

It should read:

```
"EXEC SELECT * FROM RECONCILIATION.dbo.TBL_FMDDATA_HIST_SPLIT 
WHERE AsOfDate between '" & StartDate & "'" & " AND " & "'" & EndDate & "'"
```