# How to change declared variable in OLE DB Query by editing a cell from Excel?

Tags: excel, oledb

We have different connections and different pivot tables connected to them in our Excel sheet and we don't want to edit them each time using data-> properties-> definitions (editing) to get them updated.

[image]

It would be much greater if we had just cells to edit

For example:

[image]

And write someting like this:

[image]

In my case i get an error of course but maybe you know how avoid it?

Comment: Have you tested this with your work?  What was the outcome?  Knowing "if this works" seems ideal for a personal test.  If you have an error, [please edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58506736/edit) to include the error.  Will flag as `Too Broad` in the interim, as numerous ways could exist for this, which is out of scope for this forum, intended for specific, objective answers to questions.

Comment: @Cyril Have the question become more clear to you?

Comment: The following should help, probably from Step 11 onward: [Parameter Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26443279/8670372)

Comment: @Xabier Did you face the similiar problem as i?

Comment: @MaksymMoroz Of course, we all face problems and find solutions,... It's not that difficult, change the definition of your SQL to have a ? instead of a value and when you click OK on the dialog box, it will prompt you to select the Cell that will hold the variable value,...

Comment: @Xabier [Parameter Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413092/how-to-use-parameterized-query-in-excel-using-column-as-parameter/26443279#26443279) here they use Database query but in my case i have OLE DB query and the Parameters... button is disabled for me

Comment: @Xabier I got an error if i write  `declare @PrevDate as datetime = ?`

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508283/10595361) this link tells that we may use only vba to cope with my problem but that code of vba is too complicated for understanding to customize it for me

Comment: [Excel VBA pass parameter to OLEDBConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722443/excel-vba-pass-parameter-to-oledbconnection) Helped me to solve the problem